# Match all occurrences of dot and replace with hyphens after word in string

Tags: python, regex

Take this string

```
version = follow('java.coding.language_v1','3.2.4')
```

After the word **follow** I would like to replace all dots with hyphens on everything before the comma, there are many strings which will follow the same pattern BUT the number of dots will vary before the comma:

Example
After conversion, the string will look like this:

```
version = follow('java-coding-language_v1','3.2.4')
```

I've using a positive lookbehind which gets to the point in the string I want to start replacing the dots with hyphens but just can match on the dots after that.

`(?<=follow\(')`

Comment: I don't understand your string. How's that actually?

Answer (score 1):

```
version = "follow('java.coding.language_v1','3.2.4')"
print (version[0:version.find(",")].replace(".","-")+version[version.find(","):])
```

- `version[0:version.find(",")]` Get the prefix of the string till it ends with "," (`follow('java.coding.language_v1'`)
- `version[0:version.find(",")].replace(".","-")` Replace .'s with -'s in the prefix string (`follow('java-coding-language_v1'`)
- `version[0:version.find(",")].replace(".","-")+version[version.find(","):])` Append the suffix (left over) string (`follow('java-coding-language_v1','3.2.4')`)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex. Split on quotes, replace the split required and join them:

```
version = "follow('java.coding.language_v1','3.2.4')"

splits = version.split("'", 2)
version = "'".join([splits[0], splits[1].replace('.', '-'), splits[2]])

# follow(java-coding-language_v1,'3.2.4')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regex, the look-ahead should be looking for the *last* part, not the first part, so that it can prevent matches *inside* that last `(...)` sequence:

`\.(?=.*,'.*'\))`

"Match any regular period character provided I can still see the `,'...')` at the end of the string"

No "match group" logic is necessary, you only matched the `.`'s, replace with `_`.

https://regex101.com/r/a6QiDZ/4/